# On a cauchy problem and the max interval on which the solution is defined.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

The problem in question is $y' = (y^2-1) xe^x$ where the initial condition is $y(1) = 2$.  I am also asked to prove that the supremum of the max interval on which the solution is defined is less than infinity.

**My solution attempt**:

I recognize this as a differential equation where I can separate variables I know that the function $y$ which is a solution to my Cauchy problem can be found by solving

$$\int_2^y \frac{1}{t^2 - 1} dt = \int_1^x s e^s ds \implies 1/2 ( -\ln|y -1| + \ln |y+1| - \ln |3|) = xe^x - e^x$$

which gives

$$\ln \sqrt{\frac{|y+1|}{3|y-1|}} = xe^x - e^x \implies \frac{|y+1|}{3|y-1|} = e^{2xe^x - 2e^x}$$

at this point I think I can forgo the absolute values since I know that My solution must be defined in an interval that includes in the range of the solution the number $2$.

Then I have $$y = \frac{-1 - 3e^{2xe^x - 2e^x}}{1 -3e^{2xe^x - 2e^x}}$$

which seems to imply that the denominator must be negative and obviously not zero, so I get

$$- \ln(3) \le 2xe^x - 2e^x$$ this is true for $x > M$ where $M$ is a big enough number but this contradicts the second question because the interval on which $y$ is defined would be as large as wanted towards $+ \infty$.

If I may I kindly ask where my mistakes are and how could they be solved.

Comment: Note that $y'>cy^2$ for some $c>0$, at least as you go forward in time. (I think $c $ can be 1, since $y^2 \geq 4$ and $x e^x \geq e $). This gives finite time blowup of $y $ (again going forward in time). I am not sure how to sharply quantify where this blowup occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your analysis is correct, apart from the fact that you've made a small sign mistake in the calculation of the $y$-integral. For $y>2$, you get
\begin{equation}
 \int_2^y \frac{1}{t^2-1}\,\text{d}t = \frac{1}{2}\left(\text{ln} |y-1| - \text{ln} |y+1| + \text{ln} \,3\right).
\end{equation}
I think that, with this information, you'll have no problems finding the maximal interval of this solution.